# gem caxlsx: send_file in rails does not download to browser - instead loads in browser window directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have implemented the export functionality in my project using caxlsx (v 3.0.4) in rails 5.2.0 with ruby 2.6.3. I have implemented the export functionality and using it twice. At one side working fine but at other end It's causing some garbage redirection instead of downloading the exported excel file. Here are my code samples:
a. In view:

```
link_to export_customers_buyers_path
```

b. In controller

```
def export_customers
    @customers = @client.customers
    package = Axlsx::Package.new
    workbook = package.workbook
    field = []
    field_new = []
    @client.custom_field_hstore.each do |field_name, _is_reuire|
      field << "#{field_name}"
      field_new << "#{field_name}"
    end
    workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'Buyers List') do |sheet|
      sheet.add_row(['S.No', field[0], field[1], field[2], field[3], field[4], field[5], field[6], field[7], field[8], field[9], field[10],
                     field[11], field[12], field[13], field[14]])
      counter = 0
      @customers.each do |customer|
        counter += 1
        sheet.add_row([counter, customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[0]], customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[1]],
                       customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[2]], customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[3]],
                       customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[4]], customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[5]],
                       customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[6]], customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[7]],
                       customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[8]], customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[9]],
                       customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[10]], customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[11]],
                       customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[12]], customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[13]],
                       customer.customer_detail_hstore[field_new[14]]])
      end
    end
    package.serialize("#{Rails.root}/tmp/basic.xlsx")
    send_file("#{Rails.root}/tmp/basic.xlsx", filename: 'Buyers.xlsx', type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel')
  end
```

c. Instead of downloading the excel file it redirects shows me some garbage values like it tried to show excel file.like this:
PK(!����� �[Content_Types].xml���n�0E��ZXJ:Ea;Cc�!�U�c!zATR��K�M�,q�LE�s��Z��Hh��ْ/X^m��f���js���z�Y�s|UN"���@���;ؙ�w���מ(Sz�"3΅CO�z�d4k��t�:�u ����&wh[��{G��]FBB��K\�V!���G�3{+0-࿯�1���dg������+�ݭ��ʝ4~����b,���r��[5?PK(!�ꍎh�9_rels/.rels���J1�_����Dd�{ao"��63Sfڔ4���V��.*x���_B��%���J�M �#�`ࡻ]]�~����J�(c�EUI*F�|�uq#F[ʘj�'�VjɃ��Mv@�i�K�_=��Su�ˬ_��G���f��׌����o�=ELr"����7��}�œ�c�JG��9���(�[���\�%`���ds����"�<�SD�D��voPK(!����'��docProps/app.xml��� �0E�doSDJ�.��P�K���{!y���F�/�r8��½Z!eO�ŮiEh�y�����(z�.�"$����Ǭ��;)�] ��)�(���L��i�Nd��m6t������[�_�#��˷���(��5/PK(!��&��docProps/core.xmlm�Qk� ǿJ�=1�])b҇�>m0X����\SY4��ɾ��m��x���ϓc�Qu� ���.�r��}#u[��z�nѮb�P�[x���%�$�iG�)��{C1v���,:���*�Ci[l���-�"�7X�� �O���FtQ6bV��EA#0t�@{�IF�?���5pw�.hV��pLfrtr��aȆU����<�ů�R;ϵT�FPa���V|�����.��$AO�k_����S�GU�$%E�oj��Ŗ>��&��|<����nV�/�X�ު�PK(!�(�͸�xl/*rels/workbook.xml.rels��� �0�_���e����v+�J��֖���VQP�«�|�OV�K߉yn��0NRd�-SI8��6�՞:�׍cOK�CpKD�5�����Ii}�Bl}�N�VU��4��e�;S��W$��o�& ��2N"D>8�Eh˲Ѵ��ؓ ���� >+��_�p:�'xP���M�o^*PK(!��'��� xl/styles.xml�T]�� �+��q�.t��Rڥ���Wg���A͒����ib��m��sν^oR��(��Ь���!�gB����wv���i`�nďN��G�V�TUD���6�nu��j'>m��׎aZUe�/�/��I�aD�*�� Pߟ�>{��dM��Қ� �3�\��ß�����J�Nr=�eE"@�0-�wP�p�4��Cδ�Ak���P��F��h��7�7�z���:-P�źN�CMB��Q�(!JW�p�ӕ]���ۅᶭғ��M�[�$��:��^Pcy!X}�$��ӭ4�*�z�.?���g�2'��쳕F�l!�t �v��SZ������1�����š ��M>�jy��E�6�f�����S+��P�.���*�I�E��潁U����|��}'$�Tx� �����I�X?�V���H�)�H�����PK(!��:>�4xl/workbook.xml��Ak�0����}uZJ�B�B)��;l?����4���ݿ�HWv�E!����-��Y"e�EsG!擃����3l��J|�$:���`(e���n��eAf����]�deb�AĒF����M>f�j���>v���0�;�q�E��'��dol�/�|��z? �m��*~����&��:�]���y�R�p��ǰV�����pjPK(!�=Xbd�ʃY�����h�i4;�f��f9U�V4'���ͭ�N��_;�gz�T������K��%�\�(/y�%O�%��*(��bu����ȴ��i? گ �y@�_�+��/��Zг'T=߯D�vS�]%{�@ȴ�%}ce/і�"�~�^���=�NxS�*��^��z[��^P��V��.�^o�b�G�f�V���t�"�C����!"#DƈL�"2;&:�Wxh<�� Aa�m��o���n���ֹd���1�|��t�U=^2�Bn�}��79�H�"}D�!2Fd����u�)�����a�9e�q�^!�[w�����a�l�"]Dz�� 2Dd��� "SDf�5���[��Y-�:wܺd�M9�pjO�i�[� ��"�C����!"#DƈL�"2s�YU;XUC�pά��,�����;��K��֗� � ��'��lC��H�>"D���#2Ad�Ȭv�6�`���Q;�ͽYv&�W��6�\�춸�g8�'˶m�a>Y�{f���C��H�>"D���#2Ad���E��G?"U�^���AڜF#N��%hb�"9�չAz�!�F_h$�ȷ�>�G��F�E�l��a���.��X3�*���Q��:���j/��g8?[�<�[+�e�o7�ݘ���yG/N-6q��.v��t�|܇nq6��PK4(!����� ���[Content_Types].xmlPK4(!�ꍎh�9��Q_rels/.relsPK4(!����'����UdocProps/app.xmlPK4(!��&����docProps/core.xmlPK4(!�(�͸���Ixl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPK4(!��'��� ��9xl/styles.xmlPK4(!��:>�4��)xl/workbook.xmlPK4(!�=Xb

Note: when I refresh this garbage page it downloads the file but stays on same garbage page

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to export_customers_buyers_path, target: '_self'
```

solved my issue